# Not able to open worklight console

Tags: mysql, database, ibm-mobilefirst

[How to set up MySQL in IBM Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009452/how-to-set-up-mysql-in-ibm-worklight)

I followed the above link to connect mysql with worklight. But After I uncomment the mysql properties in worklight.properties file, I am not able to open the worklight console. I got the following error in the console.

Application Error

SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized:300'

javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project /sampleApp

at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:300)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]

Answer (score 0):

This means that you did not place a MySQL JDBC Connector/J driver (a .jar file) at your_project\server\lib.

Double-check this.

You can download it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
Download, extract, use the .jar file within.